# AWS - added SSL to load balancer and tried accessing https url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

i have a ssl certificate issued for my website url. Also, i have attached it as  listener to load balancer with port 443. Also, in route 53 i have an record set for the same application url with ELB selected as alias to it.

Then, if my pc - connected to a network and then i tried to ping the application url from command prompt, i got the correct ELB IP to which my application is pointing to. But,

after that, if i move from one network to other and then tried to ping from command prompt,
i got wrong ELB IP.

I really don't understand what is happening ? and why ssl is not working for a network and for other it is working finely ?

Please let me know, if someone knows the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you have a ELB is designed for High Availability with multiple servers behind which is the reason why when DNS alias resolved, it gives different IP. This is not an issue.

If you are unable to access from a different Network, it can be due to multiple reasons. Few of them are

- Security group is not configured properly for other network
- ELB is private
- Routing Tables or NACLs not properly configured

Comment: Thanks, i have checked security groups attached to ELB, and also other options you have mentioned here.. All looks ok. And sorry to ask you again but, i only have one server in my ELB for now. Thats why, i am unable to get your point that -------"when you have a ELB is designed for High Availability with multiple servers behind which is the reason why when DNS alias resolved, it gives different IP."

Comment: @ruser the ELB is a separate device from your server. It doesn't matter how many servers you have behind the ELB, the IP address of the ELB itself is subject to change. You should use the DNS name of the ELB instead of the IP, and not worry about the IP of the ELB changing.

Comment: @MarkB my website domain is pointing to ELB DNS Name from Route 53 in AWS and then, from command prompt on my machine, if i ping with ELB's DNS name then, it will give me different ip than at the same time when i ping with the domain name of same website. So, why it is happening ?